# Sharepoint 2010 failed to apply web.config modifications to Web Application

Tags: feature-activation, spwebconfigmodification

I have a SharePoint solution deployed into a specific web application on the production SharePoint site.

When I try to enable the feature from the site features in Site Settings I get an error saying it "Failed to apply web.config modifications to the web application" and the access to the web.config file is denied.

When we tried this on test we had no problems.

Does anyone know why this would be the case and how it can be resolved?

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: Probably permissions - what account is the code that applies the modifications running under?

Answer (score 1):

Check the permission on the inetpub folders or the folder of that web app and compare with the permission in test environment.